# Is it ever OK to not chain initializers in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am coding in Objective-C / Cocoa-Touch for iPhone, and I was wondering, is it ever OK to not chain initializers? For instance, in my parent class I have three initializers that all need to be inherited from by child class. Is it OK in this instance to not chain? For instance, in this one class I have it set up like this:

```
- (id)initWithGraphic:(Graphic*)graphic size:(CGSize)size
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    if (self) 
    {
      ...

    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithGraphic:(Graphic*)graphic maximumDimension:(CGFloat)maximumDimension
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    if (self) 
    {
      ...

    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithGraphic:(Graphic*)graphic 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    if (self) 
    {
      ...

    }
    return self;
}
```

So essentially I don't have one designated initializer because it's tough for me to chain them together, I basically have three.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question--however you always need to call one of your superclass's parent initializers so that can in turn eventually call `-init`

Comment: Nielsbot, I believe that is the answer to the question: No, it not OK: Your initializer must call one of its parent class initializers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: if you want your code to be understandable and maintainable, then **you must always call `super`'s designated initializer.**

Long answer...

The `-[NSObject init]` method is [documented to do nothing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The `init` method defined in the `NSObject` class does no initialization; it simply returns `self`.

Therefore in theory you're not required to call it.  In practice **it's better to call it** because it makes your code more uniform (and therefore easier to understand), and less likely to break if you decide to change a class to inherit from something other than `NSObject`.

If you have some inheritance chain `MyGrandparent > MyParent > MyObject`, and you are the implementer of both `MyParent` and `MyObject`, and `MyParent` doesn't override all of `MyGrandparent`'s initializers, then you could directly call one of `MyGrandparent`'s non-overridden initializers from your `MyObject` initializers.  But again, **this is a bad idea**.  It will be confusing when you or someone else has to revisit the code later, and likely to break if you change the implementation of `MyParent` later.

Also, if you're creating multiple initializers, you need to learn about *designated initializers* [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW58).  It's important to pick one of your initializers as the designated initializer, and make sure all subclass initializers call the superclass's designated initializer directly.  Otherwise, you're likely to end up creating infinite recursion.  I explained this problem thoroughly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310899/about-parent-objects-init-method/12311246#12311246) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057461/why-cant-a-designated-initializer-call-a-secondary-initializer-in-its-base-clas/10057624#10057624).

#### UPDATE

In your example, you could set up a designated initializer like this:

```
static CGFloat const kMaximumDimensionNone = 0; // or NAN if 0 is a valid max dimension
static CGSize const kSizeNone = { 0, 0 }; // or NAN, NAN if 0x0 is a valid size

- (id)initWithGraphic:(Graphic *)graphic size:(CGSize)size maximumDimension:(CGFloat)maximumDimension {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _graphic = graphic;
        if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(size, kSizeNone)) {
            [self configureWithSize:size];
        }
        else if (maximumDimension != kMaximumDimensionNone) {
            // Use if(!isnan(maximumDimension)) instead if you use NAN as the placeholder
            [self configureWithMaximumDimension:maximumDimension];
        }
        else {
            [self configureWithDefaultDimensions];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithGraphic:(Graphic *)graphic {
    return [self initWithGraphic:graphic size:kSizeNone maximumDimension:kMaximumDimensionNone];
}

- (id)initWithGraphic:(Graphic *)graphic size:(CGSize)size {
    return [self initWithGraphic:graphic size:size maximumDimension:kMaximumDimensionNone];
}

- (id)initWithGraphic:(Graphic *)graphic maximumDimension:(CGFloat)maximumDimension {
    return [self initWithGraphic:graphic size:kSizeNone maximumDimension:kMaximumDimensionNone];
}
```

You don't have to expose the designated initializer in the public header file.  You can add a a separate header file exposing the designated initializer for subclasses to import.  For example, Apple does this with the `UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h` header, which declares the `ForSubclassEyesOnly` category on `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Or you could expose the `configureWith...` methods to your subclasses, and maybe you wouldn't even need to have them override the initializers.

Comment: Thanks for the response as usual Rob. I wasn't clear in my question, what I meant was, if you have multiple initializers in one class, is it OK to not chain them together as long as each one of them calls the super classes initializer?

Comment: @CoDEFRo Perhaps you could edit your question to include an example of what you're considering.

Comment: Just out of curiosity is the scenario I presented at top ever warranted?

Comment: Ever?  I don't know.  I don't tend to worry about making one designated initializer unless I intend a class to be subclassed.  But as soon as I start thinking about subclassing it, I make sure it has a designated initializer (if the class even has multiple initializers).